# How can i search tensorflow's corresponding api message as a string about layer in my program?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want a function whose's input is the layer's name and the output is it's _init API?
for example:
input is Conv2D, and output is its API as a string like below:

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None,
    dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros',
    kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs
)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AStopher get tensorflow init API message for  some tensorflow layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that with [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```py
import inspect
import tensorflow as tf
callable = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D
sig = inspect.signature(callable)
print(f'{callable.__module__}.{callable.__name__}{s}')
# tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs)
```

The module name corresponds to the module where the callable is actually implemented, which is the information you can get from the object but does not necessarily match the name that you use to access it (in the case of TensorFlow at least).

If you want to wrap it to a certain line width you can use the builtin [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module, or for something more sophisticated a proper Python code formatter like [black](https://github.com/psf/black), [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) or [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8).